# Where can I download Windows Automation API from?

Tags: automation, ui-automation

Where can I download Windows Automation API from? or is it present in the windows 7 sdk itself . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms726294.aspx) is provided out-of-the-box with Windows starting with Vista (with Windoww XP, you need to download a redistributable package).

The Windows SDK provides the necessary `.h` files (UIAutomation.h, UIAutomationClient.h, UIAutomationCore.h, UIAutomationCoreApi.h) in the standard `include` directory.